# VBA conditional formatting cells with value that are greater than or less than

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write a macro code that will do the followings for a range of cells

1. Conditional formatting will only apply if the cell has been entered a value
2. If the value in the cell is less than $I$6 and/or greater than $M$6 , highlight red, if not, do not highlight (or don't apply).

This is used as a specification check on the data that is entered to make sure the numbers are within the spec range. Thanks!

What I tried:

```
Sub SpecCheck()
    Dim iRow As Range
    Set iRow = Range("f16:l34")

    For Each cell In iRow
        If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > "I6" And cell.Value < "M6" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

New code I tried, which didn't work. Also not sure if matters, but the code is written in the "general" code for the worksheet.

```
Sub SpecCheck()

Dim iRow As Range, cell As Range 
Dim lowSpec As Range
Dim highSpec As Range
Set iRow = Range("f16:l34")
Set lowSpec = Range("r6")
Set highSpec = Range("s6")

For Each cell In iRow
 If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > highSpec And cell.Value < lowSpec Then
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: **`I'm trying to write a macro code`**... ok, so what happened to it...? SO is NOT **`"Write code for me site"`**. Show us what have you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sub SpecCheck()

Dim iRow As Range
Set iRow = Range("f16:l34")

For Each cell In iRow
    If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > "I6" And cell.Value < "M6" Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that those are ranges, not strings:

```
Sub SpecCheck()
Dim iRow As Range, cell as Range ' I also added the cell as Range
Set iRow = Range("f16:l34")

For Each cell In iRow
    If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > Range("$I$6").Value And cell.Value < Range("$M$6").Value Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Does merged cells affect the codes? My two range are in a merged cell...

Comment: @Sid.T. - Yes, it will. Can you post a quick screenshot? You'll have to unmerge, and make sure both cells have the data.  It's generally best to avoid merged cells, and just work with a formatting to make them look merged, IMO. Can you clarify though? `$I$6` is something like `Value is 123` and you just need to check against `123`?

Comment: just to check if it was the merged cells, I changed the cell range to r6 and s6. The values I want to check are if lower than 299 and if higher than 311.Private Sub SpecCheck()

Dim iRow As Range, cell As Range ' I also added the cell as Range
Dim lowSpec As Range
Dim highSpec As Range
Set iRow = Range("f16:l34")
Set lowSpec = Range("r6")
Set highSpec = Range("s6")

For Each cell In iRow
    If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value > highSpec And cell.Value < lowSpec Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next

End Sub

Comment: @Sid.T. - Can you post that into your OP, and format as code? It's hard to read here.